# SFMC - How to update custom object record data after it entered on journey?

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, dataextensions

I have a custom object record that is entering in a journey when created.

I have a decision split to check if it's status (custom field) changed to value *x* (when it entered it had value *y*). I noticed that my journey wasn't being able to see that the value had changed, after some googling i discovered it was because I was using *Journey Data* in my decision split instead of *Contact Data* **but** it seems that I can't use contact data on this custom object of mine (there's no option for it) and I wasn't able to find any relevant links online.

Is there any way to do this?

I'm currently using Salesforce Data as my entry point. I tried with a D.E but it didn't work as well

Answer (score 0):

We may need a little more information from you to give you a confident answer.
Here are my assumptions, please correct me if I they are wrong:

1. You are using an SF Entry Event for the Journey Entry set on your Custom Object.
2. (KEY ASSUMPTION, please validate)This Custom Object is NOT related to Contact ID/Lead ID/User ID.
3. In the SF Entry Event Entry data you are selecting this particular Custom Field with Value Y present.

In this situation, the MC connector enables you to create an SF Entry Event on any SF Object. But because you have created this SF Entry Event on an object that is NOT related to Contact ID/Lead ID/User ID, this Custom Object will NOT be configured in your BU's Data Designer Marketing Cloud Connect Attribute group. As it is not configured in the Data Designer Marketing Cloud Connect Attribute group, you will not be able to leverage the Contact Data in the Decision Split.

**HIGH LEVEL SOLUTION WITH SF ENTRY EVENT (REAL TIME REOCRD INJECTION):**
I recommend either working with you SF CRM Devs to update you Custom Object to relate to the Contact ID/Lead ID/User ID. OR working with you SF CRM Devs to migrate that Custom Field you care about in your decision split onto an object that is already related to the Contact ID/Lead ID/User ID. You will be able to then use contact data in your decision split to perform the decisioning you desire.

**HIGH LEVEL SOLUTION WITH AUTOMATION ENTRY (SCHUDLED REOCRD INJECTION):** You could create an Automation using SQL Queries to pull the eligible audience and inject them into the journey with a DE journey entry. You will have to frequently update a DE with the custom field value (via automation) for the Decision Split to reliably check for the most up-to-date data and you will have to manually link 1 or 2 custom DEs to your data designer data model. There are also a bunch of limitations with this though. You will lose the real time trigger element and you will also have to have more technical capabilities to manage this build.